# Collision normal in a manifold between two rectangles

Tags: collision-detection, physics

I am writing a physics engine by copying codes from an existing one. For collisions I need the collision manifold with the following information:

- Collision Point 1
- Collision Point 2
- Collision Normal

For simplicity this is between two rotatable rectangles in 2D. or 3D is ok too.

I did some research and code works in three steps:

There are 2 colliders, you put them in GJK you get a simplex you put them in EPA you get collision normal and penetration depth.

Now last step is called clipping_get_contact_manifold convex_convex_contact_manifold, that finds the two collision points using clipping. Also using like

sutherland_hodgman
// Based on https://research.ncl.ac.uk/game/mastersdegree/gametechnologies/previousinformation/physics5collisionmanifolds/

I've found one other information about this subject:

https://dyn4j.org/2011/11/contact-points-using-clipping/

I still don't quite understand this method, or what to search for.

Any extra resources or some guidance would be helpful.

Comment: "3D is ok too" no, a 3D manifold is a polygon, not a line segment like the output you've described. Is your question how to find the intersecting segment given two overlapping rectangles? Do you have relative velocity information available to distinguish the incident direction?

Comment: I am not sure what these mean, but I think collision point 1 is the deepest penetration point for first entity, and other is for the second entity. here's the reference for convex hulls https://github.com/felipeek/raw-physics/blob/238f6e192adcb1529222375426959a29d527570a/src/physics/clipping.cpp#L249 .
I think in 3d it finds a bunch of these for every face of the rectangle.

Comment: A rectangle is also a convex hull, so are you able to simply use the existing code you've linked?

Comment: just to be clear, the algorithm is seperating axis theorem, GJK, or Expanding Polytype Algorithm. Is that correct.

Comment: Those are three different algorithms used for collision detection. It's not clear to me what question you're asking about them.

Comment: Bro you know exactly what I am talking about, The algorithms I mentioned doesnt find the two collision points they only find the normal and penetration. What is this clipping contact manifold algorithm that finds these collision points. I don't understand why you make me repeat it.

Comment: Because that's not what you said, so I was not able to glean that meaning..When people ask you a question, it's often because they genuinely need more information. So, if this code is not doing what you want, why did you link it? What information were you hoping a reader would glean from that link?

Comment: I am looking for further reference on this subject the code uses, to get a better explanation. Some official technical academic article or a book. I have no idea about this subject, and its so complicated, some cross references would be helpful.